# Is there a CI service which uses qemu as isolation?

Tags: linux, open-source, virtualization, continuous-integration

My crucial criteria for the choice of a continous integration (CI) service is isolation.

After getting started with `hudson` and `gump` I realized that the isolation against the running system has to be performed by me as administrator of the service rather than the service and that seems to be the case for many others (`Luntbuild`, `jenkins`).

For example

- in order to be able to allow test code to run `sudo` I need to setup at least a `chroot` or let the service run in a container and that still leaves me without support for different containers for different projects - all things I'd expect a service to do for me.
- If I'd want to test project x in Debian 7, OpenSUSE 13.1 and Gentoo, I'd have to code that in my test/CI setup routine (including creation of `qemu` instances, resetting to initial snapshot of those before each start and retrieval of success/failure result and logs/console output. So sum it up I'd have to code 90 % of the functionality I'm requesting myself because isolation seems like an underestimated feature.

Online CI services like travis-ci.org deal with exactly that problem and pretty much do what I'm describing (except for the transparent support of different OSs), except with Linux 2.6.x (at least until tomorrow ;), so I want (for these reasons and pure independency) to run my own instance.

What combination of existing tools would minimize the need to implement things myself - assuming that the overhead of setting up and administrating a large number of services doesn't count as workload?

I'm looking for a solution involving open source and preferrably FLOSS software only which can run on Linux 4.x.